# Spring Batch takes one minute before termination

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

After the completion of my Spring Batch job, it takes about one minute till the shutdown hook is launched.
As I am still learning how to use the framework, I am quite sure I misconfigured something.

My job and step is straightforward: read data from a database and write it back in another table.

```
@Bean
public Job importUserJob(Step step1)
{
return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                        .flow(step1)
                        .end()
                        .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step1(JdbcCursorItemReader<User> reader, SaveAllRepositoryItemWriter<User> writer)
{
return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                         .<User, User> chunk(1000)
                         .reader(reader)
                         .writer(writer)
                         .build();
}
```

`SaveAllRepositoryItemWriter` is a simplified version of `RepositoryItemWriter`, which takes a `CrudRepository` and calls `CrudRepository.saveAll()` in it's `write()`-method (see below).

The last lines of the log output is as follows:

```
2020-05-28 10:53:57.213  INFO 5964 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=importUserJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=23}]
2020-05-28 10:53:57.264  INFO 5964 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
2020-05-28 10:53:57.643  WARN 5964 --- [           main] c.n.d.SaveAllRepositoryItemWriter        : Writing finished
2020-05-28 10:53:57.664  INFO 5964 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step1] executed in 400ms
2020-05-28 10:53:57.676  INFO 5964 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=importUserJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=23}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 441ms
2020-05-28 10:54:57.002  INFO 5964 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-28 10:54:57.004  INFO 5964 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-28 10:54:57.004  INFO 5964 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-05-28 10:54:57.006  INFO 5964 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

I added the log output `Writing finished` to ensure that the Writer has actually written the data, as I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019717/spring-batch-exiting-with-exit-status-completed-before-actual-job-is-finished) that it might be a problem.

If I did not provide enough information, I am happy to provide more information.

---

```
public class SaveAllRepositoryItemWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<T>, InitializingBean
{
  private CrudRepository<T, ?> repository;
  protected static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(SaveAllRepositoryItemWriter.class);

  public void setRepository(CrudRepository<T, ?> repository)
  {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  /**
   * Check mandatory properties - there must be a repository.
   */
  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception
  {
    Assert.state(repository != null, "A CrudRepository implementation is required");
  }

  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception
  {
    this.repository.saveAll(items);
    logger.warn("Writing finished");
  }
}
```

Debug Log:

```
2020-05-28 11:27:15.541 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step execution complete: StepExecution: id=25, version=3, name=step1, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0
2020-05-28 11:27:15.541 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2020-05-28 11:27:15.541 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(1002762002<open>)] for JPA transaction
2020-05-28 11:27:15.541 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@50448409]
2020-05-28 11:27:15.541 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2020-05-28 11:27:15.541 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE SPRING_BATCH.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2020-05-28 11:27:15.547 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
2020-05-28 11:27:15.547 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1002762002<open>)]
2020-05-28 11:27:15.548 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1002762002<open>)] after transaction
2020-05-28 11:27:15.548 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.b.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow   : Completed state=importUserJob.step1 with status=COMPLETED
2020-05-28 11:27:15.548 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.b.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow   : Handling state=importUserJob.COMPLETED
2020-05-28 11:27:15.548 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.b.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow   : Completed state=importUserJob.COMPLETED with status=COMPLETED
2020-05-28 11:27:15.549 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.AbstractJob           : Job execution complete: JobExecution: id=25, version=1, startTime=Thu May 28 09:27:15 UTC 2020, endTime=null, lastUpdated=Thu May 28 09:27:15 UTC 2020, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=exitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=25, version=0, Job=[importUserJob]], jobParameters=[{run.id=25}]
2020-05-28 11:27:15.550 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2020-05-28 11:27:15.550 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(708004780<open>)] for JPA transaction
2020-05-28 11:27:15.550 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@470d183]
2020-05-28 11:27:15.550 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2020-05-28 11:27:15.550 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT VERSION FROM SPRING_BATCH.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?]
2020-05-28 11:27:15.551 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2020-05-28 11:27:15.551 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SPRING_BATCH.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2020-05-28 11:27:15.555 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2020-05-28 11:27:15.555 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE SPRING_BATCH.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION set START_TIME = ?, END_TIME = ?,  STATUS = ?, EXIT_CODE = ?, EXIT_MESSAGE = ?, VERSION = ?, CREATE_TIME = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ? and VERSION = ?]
2020-05-28 11:27:15.556 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
2020-05-28 11:27:15.556 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(708004780<open>)]
2020-05-28 11:27:15.557 DEBUG 9984 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(708004780<open>)] after transaction
2020-05-28 11:27:15.557  INFO 9984 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=importUserJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=25}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 247ms
2020-05-28 11:28:15.069 DEBUG 9984 --- [extShutdownHook] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@13e39c73, started on Thu May 28 09:27:12 UTC 2020
2020-05-28 11:28:15.072  INFO 9984 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-28 11:28:15.073  INFO 9984 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-28 11:28:15.074  INFO 9984 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-05-28 11:28:15.075  INFO 9984 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Info-Log with around 100'000 items:

```
2020-05-28 15:01:58.230  INFO 8172 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=importUserJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=5}]
2020-05-28 15:01:58.275  INFO 8172 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
2020-05-28 15:02:03.640  INFO 8172 --- [           main] c.n.d.SaveAllRepositoryItemWriter        : Written 10000 items.
2020-05-28 15:02:13.757  INFO 8172 --- [           main] c.n.d.SaveAllRepositoryItemWriter        : Written 10000 items.
...
2020-05-28 15:04:24.750  INFO 8172 --- [           main] c.n.d.SaveAllRepositoryItemWriter        : Written 8512 items.
2020-05-28 15:04:29.041  INFO 8172 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step1] executed in 2m30s766ms
2020-05-28 15:04:29.065  INFO 8172 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=importUserJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=5}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 2m30s816ms
2020-05-28 15:04:29.068  INFO 8172 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-28 15:04:29.070  INFO 8172 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-28 15:04:29.071  INFO 8172 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-05-28 15:04:29.073  INFO 8172 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://some_ip:5432/some_db
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pw

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
spring.jooq.sql-dialect=Postgres

spring.flyway.schemas = my_schema
spring.flyway.default-schema = my_schema

# Write metadata into own schema
# See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057739/2021763 for an explanation
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
spring.batch.table-prefix=SPRING_BATCH.BATCH_
spring.batch.schema=classpath:db/create_spring_batch_tables.sql
```

Dependencies in the `pom.xml` (omitted test-scope)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set logging to debug?

Comment: Yes, but the one minute break is also there. I updated the answer and posted the last lines. Perhaps it takes so long to close the JPA EntityManager?

Comment: According to the logs, the job took `247ms` to complete and it looks like closing the application context is what taking a minute to finish (probably due to closing the JPA entity manager indeed). Can you share your JPA config and your Hikari pool settings? Do you have other resources using JPA other than you job?

Comment: At the moment the project has only one job and nothing else, so there should not be any other resources. After I read your comment, I executed the application with more items to load and write and the the job takes around 2 minutes and there is no waiting period. (Posted the log output in the question.) I also posted my application.properties and part of my pom.xml as these are the only settings I have. At least I am only aware of those.

Comment: curious behaviour indeed.. I can't see from what you shared what could be the reason for that.